# related user linking with user and employee in odoo 9 in coustom module?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I created a custom module for automatic user creation while an employee was created.It work properly but  the link between user and employee not yet created (related user not yet created)

[related user not linking with user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi5qV.png)

[image]

```xml
<record id="view_users_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook" position="inside">

                <field name="employee_id" readonly="1" required="0" groups="base.group_no_one"

                                attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id', '=', False)]}"/>

        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    result = super(ResUsersInherit, self).create(vals)
    print vals
    result['employee_id'] = self.env['res.users'].create({'name': vals['name'],'login': vals['work_email']})

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override (extend) create method of `hr.employee` and in that you need to write below code.

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    result = super(ResUsersInherit, self).create(vals)
    print vals
    user = self.env['res.users'].create({'name': vals['name'],'login': vals['work_email']})
    result['employee_id'] = user and user.id or False

    return result
```

**Problem :**

You were assigning object instead of id, so I have just replace object with id.

Comment: This is not the solution. i need to find the partner_id passed to the user_id from user to employee module